# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'octokit' imported

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this javascript:

**myrepo/src/sample.js**

```
// Octokit.js
// https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme

import { Octokit, App } from "octokit";

var start = async function(a, b) { 
  const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: 'ghp_****'
  })
  await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/secrets/public-key', {
    owner: 'myowner',
    repo: 'myrepo',
    headers: {
      'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
    }
  })
}
```

with this package.json file:

**myrepo/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "samples",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "author": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "email": "john@mail.com"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": "./src/samples.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "samples": "node src/samples.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@octokit/rest": "^18.12.0",
    "@octokit/core": "4.2.0"
  }
}
```

But get this error:

```
❯ npm i
  ....
❯ npm run samples

node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'octokit' imported from /Users/..../src/sample.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:860:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:909:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

So seems the script is not aware of the node_modules folder that contains the octokit packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the `@octokit/core` module instead of simply `octokit` (note: they are two distinct NPM packages, but you only have `@octokit/core` installed). From the [README](https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme):

> Install with npm install `@octokit/core`
>
> ```js
> const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/core");
> // or: import { Octokit } from "@octokit/core";
> ```

So, try changing this line in your code

```
import { Octokit, App } from "octokit";
```

to

```
import { Octokit, App } from "@octokit/core";
```

If you **are** in fact looking for the [`octokit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/octokit) package, then you'll need run `npm install octokit` to install that package. You'll probably want to run `npm remove @octokit/core` to remove the other (more minimal) package too.